# Disjoint vs non disjoint sets & order relation

Tags: order-theory

is the existence of an order relation (such as $a\leq{b}$) a distinctive feature of disjoint vs non-disjoint sets (for instance, intervals of R)? Thanks

Comment: As far as I could infer your question: The answer is No: For Eg: $S_1=\{1,2,3\}$ and $S_2=\{3,4,5\}$ and $S_3=\{7,8,9\}$. The Order relation exists for each set but $S_1\cap S_2\neq \phi $ and $S_1\cap S_3 =\phi$

Comment: Have a look at it too. [order and binary relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11991), [Order relation on two Disjunct sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915732)